# how to grab a value using a link

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

i am trying to bind an id to a  tag. not sure if i should do a bind
but i hope my example would help to explain what i am trying to do.
i have a php for loop that gives me a series of numbers

```
<?php

         for($value = 1; $value <=5; $value++){
         print '<br><form><input id="hidden" type="hidden" value="'.$value.'" /><a id="link">click here</a><form>';
         }
         ?>
```

in my html i have a field within a form when the while loop is executed html looks like this

```
<input id="hidden" type="hidden" value="1" /><a id="link">click here</a>
<input id="hidden" type="hidden" value="2" /><a id="link">click here</a>
<input id="hidden" type="hidden" value="3" /><a id="link">click here</a>
```

my aim is this. if i click on the first 'click here' i want to output the hidden value of 1
if i click on the second 'click here' i want to output hidden value of 2 and etc.. my problem 
is that when i click on either link, i only get back the value of the first 'click here' which is 1

this is my jquery code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("a#link").click(function(){
    var s = $('.hidden').val();
 alert(s); 
 }); 
}); 
</script>
```

thanks for your help in advance...

Comment: You can't use 3 times the same id for `hidden` & `link`, use instead class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.hidden').val()
```

will always just give you the first hidden val in the DOM.  You need

```
$(this).prev("#hidden").val()
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RJJEr/

Answer (score 1):

never ever use the identical `id`s change it to class

```
<input id="hidden" type="hidden" value="1" />
<a class="link" href="#">click here</a>
<input id="hidden" type="hidden" value="2" />
<a class="link">click here</a>
<input id="hidden" type="hidden" value="3" />
<a class="link">click here</a>
```

and the jquery part has already been answered by @DavidGouge

```
    $("a.link").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var s = $(this).prev("input").val();
 alert(s);
 });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5q2j7/8/)

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique, you can use `class='hidden'` instead of `id="hidden"` and in your function you have used `var s = $('.hidden').val()` but there is no `'hidden'` class in your form.